# How to code an application in Python/Wayland/Linux that uses multiple mice as distinct inputs?

Tags: wayland, input-method

I'd like to write an application that emulates jeopardy buzzers. There would be one host computer connected to N mice, which act as each player's buzzers.

What would be the *simplest* way to write this application in Python? An ideal solution would avoid tampering or creating new physical hardware.

Options I'm considering:

- I've heard USB devices are read by the OS as a plaintext stream somewhere. But where?
- I could also bind each button to a different key, and just listen for keyboard events. Is it possible to bind right-click on mouse-0 to key-0, but right-click on mouse-1 to key-1? or do all right-clicks get bound to the same key?

There are so many options, I am wondering what is the easiest? Also a lot of the reading I've done is specific to X11 (`xinput this` or `xev that`). How should one do the equivalent in Wayland?

Comment: you could get several scrap USB keyboards ... remove the key matrix and wire a single button to the keyboard controller

Comment: For the purposes of this question, let's only consider software solutions. Physical solutions have disadvantages, being too hard or being difficult to undo. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I understand that you are seeking a software solution ... it was just the first thought that popped into my head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plug in several usb mice, they will each appear as a new device named, for example, `/dev/input/event9`. The utility `evtest` will interactively list them all, and add what type of device they appear to be, eg:

```
/dev/input/event9:      Logitech USB Optical Mouse
```

If you then run

```
evtest --grab /dev/input/event9
```

you will see data printed each time you move that mouse, or click its buttons.
The `--grab` will also prevent these events from going on to the Wayland (or X11) server.

You can write a script around this to implement your game, or you can do
the same thing programmatically from Python3 with the package
[evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).